# Convert HEX to Decimal in Query

Tags: sql, oracle, hex

I'm looking to convert a hexadecimal number from an Oracle database
(just need it in a query to to pull into PowerBI, so no DB alterations).

I have a `RAW` field where I take a `SUBSTR` of 8 characters:

```
003A2FD2 (HEX) = 3813330 (DEC)
```

How do I get to this result?

Googling this issue I've seen the function `TO_NUMBER`, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_NUMBER` does work, but you probably misused it.

```
SQL> select to_number('003A2FD2', 'xxxxxxxx') hex_to_dec from dual;

HEX_TO_DEC
----------
   3813330

SQL>
```

I presume you didn't match number of `x` with number of the hex digits (if there are 8 digits in the hex number, you have to use 8 `x`'s.